# Value does not fall within the expected range powershell job creation

Tags: powershell

I wrote some code on my Windows 7 administration machine, where it just worked fine. Now I want to run it from a console - commandline with administration access from a client machine on Windows 10.

The script throws the error when it tries to Register the task through the COM-Object of the Task-Scheduler:

> Value does not fall within the expected range:

```
    # Aufruf in der command line mit
# powershell.exe -file C:\Workspace\controlling-macros\TaskCreator.ps1
$path = "C:\Workspace\controlling-macros\FullWorkbookPathsMR.csv"

$csv = Import-CSV -Path $path -Delimiter ";" | % {

    # The name of the scheduled task
    [string]$TaskName = "$($_.reportsource) - $($_.reportname) - $($_.reportid)"
    # The description of the task
    [string]$TaskDescr = "Hello, it's you again! I am $($_.reportname) and I will get started, when Report ID $($_.reportid) is fired. Have a nice day!"
    # The Task Action command
    $TaskCommand0 = "cmd"
    $TaskCommand1 = "`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE`""

    # The Task Action command argument
    $TaskArg = "/c C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe /F /IM EXCEL.EXE"
    $TaskArg1 = "$($_.fullpath)"
    # attach the Task Scheduler com object
    $service = new-object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")
    # connect to the local machine. 
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381833(v=vs.85).aspx
    $service.Connect()
    $rootFolder = $service.GetFolder("\")

    $TaskDefinition = $service.NewTask(0) 
    $TaskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "$TaskDescr"
    $TaskDefinition.Settings.Enabled = $true
    $TaskDefinition.Settings.AllowDemandStart = $true

    $triggers = $TaskDefinition.Triggers
    #http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383915(v=vs.85).aspx
    $trigger = $triggers.Create(0) # Creates an "On an event" trigger
    $trigger.Subscription = "<QueryList><Query Id='0'><Select Path='Application'>*[System[Provider[@Name='$($_.reportsource)'] and EventID='$($_.reportid)']]</Select></Query></QueryList>"

    # "*[System[Provider[@Name='$reporttype'] and EventID=$reportid]]"

    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381841(v=vs.85).aspx
    $Action = $TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
    $action.Path = "$TaskCommand0"
    $action.Arguments = "$TaskArg"
    $Action = $TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
    $action.Path = "$TaskCommand1"
    $action.Arguments = "$TaskArg1"

    #http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381365(v=vs.85).aspx
    $rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("$TaskName", $TaskDefinition, 6, "System", $null, 5) # <<--- here the error occurs

    Write-Host $($_.sequence) $($_.reportsource) $($_.reportname) $($_.reportid) $($_.fullpath) "task created successfully."
}
```

why no data is piped to the variables?

Comment: the problem still persists, what can I do?

Comment: It seems like powershell has problems reading the data in. When I comment everything out, Write-Host just gives me blank output, so no data is assigned from the pipe. How can this be?

Comment: first of all, you just want us to fix your issue, it's better to ask question. Show us the entier error, the line number on which the error occured.

Comment: I have mentioned the line, where the error occurs already. No data is piped, and I don't know why. The variables are empty.

Answer (score 0):

I know this seems basic but I would start by matching Powershell versions first as different versions of Powershell do compile some code differently as well as some cmdlets just do not work in older versions.

Comment: OK, in version 2, it works, in version 5, it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

In new-scheduledtasksettingsset there is a compatibility switch (v1, vista, win7, win8).